# My user input takes uppercase letters different as lower case letters. It interferes with the results. Any tips?

Tags: python

```
 def palindrome():   #Before I had parameter s, but it is repetitive.
    s=raw_input ("Enter a phrase : ")     #Raw input makes the input not considered as a variable but as a string
    s.lower()
    return s[::-1]==s

palindrome()
```

2 questions.

1. Does the raw_input makes an input considered like a string?
2. And also I used the s.lower because when I tried to run "Eat Tae", it would say it wasn't a palindrome. The s.lower did not work. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lower()` is not in-place, it returns a new string.

You should either reassign it to `s` (`s = s.lower()`) or call `lower` on the input itself:

```
 s = raw_input("Enter a phrase : ").lower()
```

Answer (score 1):

In python, the two main ways of taking input is through `raw_input`, which takes the input in as a string, and `input`, which takes the variable in as the type entered like a int.

The `s.lower()` function returns a string so the proper format would be

```
s = s.lower()
```